# 2-shifted 2-form on the classifying stack 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $G$ be a reductive group. A $2$-shifted $2$-form on the classifying stack $BG$ is by definition a a morphism of quasi-coherent complexes

\begin{equation}
\mathcal O_{BG}\rightarrow (\wedge^2 \mathbb L_{BG})[2]
\end{equation}

Here $\mathbb L_{BG}\cong \mathfrak g^{\vee}[-1]$

So $\wedge^2 \mathbb L_{BG}\cong \wedge^2(\mathfrak g^{\vee}[-1])\cong(\wedge^2 \mathfrak g^{\vee})[-2]$. This follows from the standard definition of the wedge product of a complex. Also because the degree of $\mathfrak g^{\vee}$ in $\mathbb L_{BG}$ is $1$.

So a $2$-shifted $2$ is basically a map $\mathcal O_{BG}\rightarrow (\wedge^2 \mathfrak g^{\vee})[2-2]=(\wedge^2 \mathfrak g^{\vee})$ i.e., a $G$-invariant skew-symmetric $2$ form on $\mathfrak g$.

But in the literature, it is well known that it should correspond to a symmteric $G$-invariant $2$ form on $\mathfrak g$. What is the mistake in my argument?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the standard definition involve the Koszul sign, so the wedge turns into a sym in the second isomorphism of your fifth line?

Comment: @Will Sawin Can you please provide a reference where it is explained in detail? I must have misunderstood this point in my notes.

Comment: so in this case Sym^2 becomes wedge and wedge^2 becomes sym^2. ok

Comment: @S.D.: This is described in Deligne–Morgan “Notes on supersymmetry” in “Quantum Fields and Strings”.

Comment: The exterior powers of a complex are also explained in Illusie's "Complexe cotangent et deformations", where the cotangent complex of a ringed topos is first defined.

Comment: In Illusie's book, this is Formulas 4.3.4 and 4.3.5 on p. 322 of the first volume.

Comment: @Jason Starr very kind of you, thanks